# Testing JQuery button with Jest

Tags: jquery, jestjs

I'm struggling with creating a Jest test for testing the following download button:

```
function buttons() {
  $('#Download').click(function () {
    downloadRapport()
  })
}

$(document).ready(buttons());
```

I created the following test for this code:

```
describe("Download", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.restoreAllMocks();
    });

    jest.mock('jquery');
    const $ = require("jquery");
    $.ajax = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({});
    const downloadRapport = require(PATH);
    
    test('download Rapport', async () => {
        await downloadRapport.buttons()
        
        $('#Download').click();

        expect(downloadRapport.downloadRapport()).toBeCalled();

        expect($.ajax).toBeCalledWith({
            url: PATH,
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ components: components }),
            beforeSend: expect.any(Function),
            success: expect.any(Function),
            error: expect.any(Function),
        })
    });
})
```

Unfortunately, I'm receiving the following error: **ReferenceError: $ is not defined**. The error is already flaged at the line

`const downloadRapport = require(PATH);`

The JQuery is loaded as follows:

```
  <script src="/js/basics/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/basics/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/basics/xlsx.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/basics/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/basics/mto_basics.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/basics/sidebar.js"></script>
```

Can anybody help us with fixing the error in our jest test?